# Recursion in Labview - what is causing it to hang?

Tags: recursion, labview

Background: As a background I've been trying to learn LabVIEW and wanted to translate and english string to morse code. As per another post's suggestions I've solved this with a for loop, but was wondering why my recursive approach wasn't working. The way I was thinking of solving it was to have the string be split up into the 1st item in it and the rest, then check that item against a case selector for a letter that matches to the desired morse code value. The rest of the string would then become the input for the VI to run again leading to the output that collects all the strings. See attached code: [image: Labview recursion] In the image the code is running in highlight execution mode. The true case for the outer case diagram (for when the input1 is empty) merely returns the empty string constant. The recursive call (VI) is wired as shown here: [image: wiring of VI] Ignore the output (it's what I get when I run the code with nothing as an input (so the true case in the first case diagram happens). I'm just a little confused as to why my program runs indefinitely, prompting me to guess infinite recursion - but I get no such error (such as maximum depth reached). I'm honestly just curious how I could solve this problem recursively and think that maybe my true case (when string is empty) may play some role in it so for completion I've included it here: [image: truecase] Thanks for any help!

Comment: Small tip: before running the code, press CTRL+U to rearrange icons in your program, it will be much easier to read! [See here](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvhowto/keyboard_shortcuts/)

Comment: Wow, that actually made my newest project so much easier to ready. tysm

Answer (score 1):

I replicated your code as seen above, and it seemed to work fine completing its loop without concern.

[image: Duplication of example code]

The only thing I can think of is that this is not actually a code issue, but an operator issue. When you are running your code are you using 'Run', or 'Run Continuously'?

Comment: I'm just pressing run, maybe I wired the VI incorrectly.